# How best to map AD user groups and permissions in SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to understand how best tables should be designed to map Active Directory (AD) user groups.

I am implementing an asp.net application in which users will log in and execute actions or view pages.

I want to add permissions i.e. user can add a record, user can delete other users from system, user can view a webpage into SQL Server database.

My aim is to create AD user groups and map permissions for the user groups in the database but, I want to understand how to use parent-child structure of AD in my database such that if we have a user group that has access to perform permissions such as add record and delete record and if another user group inherits this user group but restricts access to delete a record then we would want to not allow the child user group to delete a record but it should allow adding of the record.

How should this be mapped?

thanks.  Any help points are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest looking at a technology such as MS Authorization Manager (AzMan), which will provide this functionality for you. It can use a database to hold the security configuration, or XML, or Active Directory itself.